# How to show a QMessageBox from a const method of a QDialog?

Tags: c++, qt

I have subclassed `QDialog` and I have created a `const` method, because I want to definitely prevent modifications of my instance. Now if a certain error occurs, I would like to use a `QMessageBox` to display it. But I can't use `this` as the parent of the message box, because `this` is `const`.

This is a pity. According to the documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#QDialog) the parent influences the default location of the new dialog and whether it shares the parent's taskbar entry. Does the parent necessarily have to be non-`const` for that...?

I see three options, none of them being obviously excellent:

- `const_cast` (seems strange to me to use `const_cast` in such a common situation)
- use `nullptr` as parent (ugly, because the message box position is worse)
- make my method non-const (ugly, because the compiler would not anymore support me in protecting the instance)

Is Qt not const-correct when it demands the parent widget to be modifiable? And is there a better solution than the `const_cast`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reason to introduce `..._cast` methods is to differntiate data castind and same time to protect from unwanted casting and make code more readable and easy search in code.

Operator `const_cast` is exactly that thing for your taks. The mark `const` in method mean that your operations will not modify any object state data. However make alert dialog or any window require modify much states in operation system and application internal data. That is the reason why it is not const opearations.

However apper and close alert dialog is not change any state in data of your object and not concern your task. So in point o view os and application state management create dialog is not const. But in ponit of view of task which you solve in your application the apearance of alert dialog is a const operation.

Therefore `const_cast` is exactly that what you need to make join of different tasks where them is intersected.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I get your point. Still I wonder why modifying "states in operation system and application internal data" means that the parent widget may not be `const`...?!

Comment: This is interface of object designed by creators. Actually it means that object passed to function (or constructor) will be used in non const manner. So you (and compiler) will know that. Some times interface methos require const references and call non const methos with const cast but it is internal and from point of view of user that is const.

Comment: Specifically parent window may not be const at least because it manage children windows and have a list of children windows and this list wil be modified (adition/removing) with new child and so on

Comment: I have asked another question, because I have doubts whether `const_cast` could then even lead to undefined behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989756/is-const-castthis-with-a-write-operation-undefined-behaviour-if-the-actual-ob.

Comment: Okay, according to the answers to my other question everything seems to be safe. Thank you again for your answer. Still I am not fully content with Qt here, since my code is not littered with `const_cast`s. ;)