# Is const_cast(this) with a write operation undefined behaviour, if the actual object is non-const?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

My question is inspired by this answer to another one of my questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56989169/2492801.

If I have an actually non-`const` object, but call one of its `const` methods, then inside the method `this` is `const` of course. If I `const_cast` away its constness and pass it to another method that performs a write operation on the object pointed to by `this`, is that undefined behaviour?

I wouldn't be surprised if it was, because `this` is really `const` inside a `const` method. On the other hand, the object itself is non-`const` so write operations are not generally forbidden.

For me it is important to know that to know how to deal with the problem described in my other question. Thank you!

Comment: If the method needs to change state it shouldn't be const to begin with.

Comment: If you check the other question, you will understand my reason for that...

Comment: Conciser using `mutable` (_"...permits modification of the class member declared mutable even if the containing object is declared const...."_) see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: @RichardCritten I don't want to modify my class members, see the other question...

Comment: Would it be possible subclass `QMessageBox` and make it `NiceBox(const QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QMessageBox(nullptr) { ... }` - which reads the parent position to position itself - but doesn't store the parent for other `NiceBox` functions to mess with?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Your commit fits better to the other question. But the answer is no, since as soons as I pass `nullptr` as parent to the message box, it is not centered with respect to the current dialog anymore, which is bad.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler I see. I don't know QT but assumed you would be able to affect the position in the ctor (since the parent is known there, and only there).

Comment: What I mean is that something like `NiceBox(const QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QMessageBox(nullptr) { if(parent) move(parent->pos()); } ` could be used to position your `QMessageBox` subclass without the need to cast.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You are right. Still, before messing around with window positioning, I prefer to do the `const_cast`s.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably simpler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not undefined. That's exactly what `const_cast` is for. As long as the object itself is non-`const` then you can cast it away with `const_cast` and do the same things with it as a non-`const` pointer.

Do note that `const_cast` is usually considered a code smell and might indicate bad design.

---

[As the standard says](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.this#1):

> In the body of a non-`static` ([class.mfct]) member function, the
>   keyword `this` is a prvalue whose value is a pointer to the object for
>   which the function is called. The type of this in a member function of
>   a class `X` is `X*`. If the member function is declared const, the type of
>   this is const `X*`, if the member function is declared `volatile`, the
>   type of this is `volatile X*`, and if the member function is declared
>   `const volatile`, the type of this is `const volatile X*`.

The type of `this` is `const X*` in your case even though the object itself is non-`const`.

---

The standard [says this](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast#3) about `const_cast`:

> For two similar types `T1` and `T2`, a prvalue of type `T1` may be
>   explicitly converted to the type `T2` using a `const_­cast`. The
>   result of a `const_­cast` refers to the original entity.

So, casting from `const X*` to `X*` is also legal.

---

Lastly, [it says](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast#6) (albeit in a note):

> [ Note: Depending on the type of the object, a write operation through
>   the pointer, lvalue or pointer to data member resulting from a
>   const_­cast that casts away a `const`-qualifier may produce undefined
>   behavior ([dcl.type.cv]). — end note  ]

And `[dcl.type.cv]` [tells us](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4):

> Any attempt to modify ([expr.ass], [expr.post.incr], [expr.pre.incr])
>   a const object ([basic.type.qualifier]) during its lifetime
>   ([basic.life]) results in undefined behavior.

Luckily, our `this` is pointing to a non-`const` object, so casting it and then modifying this object through the new non-`const` pointer doesn't trigger undefined behaviour.

---

<sub>Sorry Angew.</sub>

Comment: Well, `const_cast` is one way to avoid code duplication between const and non-const member functions that do the same thing and just return stuff with different const-ness (e.g. a vector of const or non-const pointers). In fact, it's sanctioned by Scott Meyers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/123995

Comment: @MaxLanghof But Scott Meyers does it the other way round. He `const_cast`s away the constness of the return value.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler My remark was solely in response to _"do note that `const_cast` is usually considered a code smell and might indicate bad design"_.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Very true, it's why I said might and usually, it's not always the case.

Comment: The only smell here is of one awesome chicken.

Answer (score -1):

So the point of const_cast away is to allow this type of manipulation, and you are expected to know if it is safe or not, as a programmer.

Where it could go wrong is if you have an aggregate object with "acceptable" member methods. No constructors, destructors, virtuals, mutable members, members that are themselves non-aggregates, nor may it be derived.

An instance of such an object could be declared in static space as constant, and the compiler might instance that object into a predefined immutable memory block. Performing a const_cast away on that object and trying to modify it, either with a global function or from your member function, will cause "undefined behaviour", probably an exception, possibly an uncatchable fault, almost certainly leading to program termination.

Comment: If it's declared in static space (in the case mentioned here) it will cause *actual issue*, but even if it's not it is *still* undefined behavior i.e. the program may break in future version.